# Environment variables inheritance with microservices (Laravel & Lumen)

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance, environment-variables, microservices

Recently I ran into a problem while deploying a **Lumen** microservice next to a **Laravel** app. On the same machine I have a Laravel app and a Lumen app both with different `.env` file and the default environment variables (`APP_ENV`, `DB_HOST`, `DB_DATABASE`, etc).

My **Laravel** app needs to make a request the the **Lumen** app to get some data. That's when the problem occures. When the **Lumen** app receives the request it also inherits the **Laravel**'s environment variables, making it impossible to do it's job (to connect to the database or other services that have the environment variables set in the `.env` file because all the variables are inherited from the parent request).

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Am I using the microservices architecture the right way?

**Update** with code.

*Laravel app - UsersController.php*

```
/**
 * Makes a request to the Core API and fills properties with the response data
 *
 * @param $method
 * @param $uri
 * @param array|null $data
 */
public function request($method, $uri, array $data = null)
{
    $this->api = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1/']);

    if (property_exists($this, 'uriPrefix')) $uri = $this->uriPrefix . $uri;
    $requestOptions = [
        'http_errors'   => false,
        'headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']
    ];
    if (session('api_cookie')) $requestOptions['headers']['Cookie'] = implode(';', session('api_cookie'));
    if ($data) {
        if ($method == 'GET') $requestOptions['query'] = $data;
        else if (($method == 'POST') || ($method == 'PUT')) $requestOptions['form_params'] = $data;
    }

    $response = $this->api->request($method, $uri, $requestOptions);

    session(['api_cookie' => $response->getHeader('Set-Cookie')]);

    $this->responseCode = $response->getStatusCode();
    $this->responseReasonPhrase = $response->getReasonPhrase();
    $this->responseData = $response->getBody();
}
```

When I make this request the **Lumen** app can't connect to the database because it inherits the `DB_` environment variables from the parent **Laravel** app.

Comment: How do you dispatch the request to lumen? It sounds very unlikely that .env-variables get inherited.

Comment: I dispatch it with http request. 
From the Laravel app I make a request to the Lumen app  `lumen.localhost/api/users`

Comment: Could you add your code, your env-files etc.?

Comment: They are similar. The only difference in the two would be that they would have different `APP_KEY` and different `DB_` credentials.

`APP_ENV=local`
`APP_DEBUG=true`
`APP_KEY=someRandomString`
`DB_HOST=localhost`
`DB_DATABASE=homestead`
`DB_USERNAME=homestead`
`DB_PASSWORD=secret`

Comment: Please, add your code to the question (how you dispatch the request, the API etc.). And what kind of error you get.

Comment: I did add the code. The same happens when I try a `file_get_contents()`. The variables get inherited.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem should solve itself by putting the project inside their own vhost. When projects live in their own vhost you will separate the files more easier.

This way you can have the .env fils in different folders alltogether.

I believe that what you are experiencing is that the application are bootstrapping at the same time therefore the variables are being used together.

If you are using Homestead as your VM, try creating two domains and putting your project separated and when your laravel application needs to call lumen call it by host name and it should work. (Note only one vhost can be called localhost)